# sync adapter turned off internet is not there

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I have Periodic interval of 60 Seconds for Every 60 Sec Task should be Updated.Sync Adapter works fine when Internet is there but my issue is When Internet is Disconnected Sync Adapter stops automatically,Any other hack to avoid Sync Adapter getting stopped when Internet is disabled

**Note:** I am getting data from Beacon via Bluetooth,This task does not depend on Internet, I have tried other solutions as well but sync adapter matches my requirement can anyone suggest solution which matches my requirement

Comment: for that case where you get data?

Comment: getting data from Beacons via Bluetooth